# Show Error Message with Hyperlink in Lightning

Tags: trigger, lightning, error

I am looking for a way to show an error message from a validation built into a trigger that will show a hyperlink.  I know this is not available the way it was in Classic but has anyone found a way to do this in Lightning?

Comment: Is this the same question as https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/349002/is-it-possible-to-create-direct-link-in-apex-trigger-or-any-other-solution-to-en

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to show hyperlinks on trigger validation.
Please refer to [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008z1RIAQ) developer forum post.